# Why image of an item of listview becomes small when I add a new item?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am retrieving data from firebase in a listview. When there is one item, image size remains good but it becomes small when I add another item.

I am using wrap_content for hight and width in ImageView. Some item might not have images in it that's why I can't set the height and width manually.

**Here is my list layout:**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".UserPostHistoryActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/lesswhite"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/posthistorylayer">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listuserposthistory"
            android:divider="@color/lesswhite"
            android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

**This is the item layout to display in Listview:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/postdamo"
    android:background="@color/white">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/postnametv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Username"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/postdatetv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/postnametv"
        android:layout_below="@+id/postnametv"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:text="24-Jan-2019"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/poststatustv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/postnametv"
        android:layout_below="@+id/postdatetv"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:text="Not Collected"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/postimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/poststatustv"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:maxHeight="250dp"
        tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detailtxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/postimage"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:text="Details:"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Use fixed size of height width of your ImageView.

Comment: @Al-Amin few item will not contain images.

Comment: @RehanSarwar if some of the items do not have images use different layouts and inflate them according to the view type you want. there are may examples of the same on SO

Comment: @RehanSarwar use simple logic in your adapter class - 

When don't have image to show then setVisibility of your imageview to `imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

Comment: Can you post your target view?

Comment: @Al-Amin After using fixed width and height and making invisible ImageView when no images, then a gap is created in place of ImageView

Comment: Is there anyway to set the position of detailstxt below poststatustv?

Comment: @RehanSarwar Post your view what do you want actually.

Comment: @RehanSarwar if you don't want to display image content when image not available at firebase server just make it visible gone else you make it visible.
set height and width of the image in your adapter_item.

Comment: @RehanSarwar first tell why your item layout match_parent?

Comment: @MaheshKeshvala after setting the height and width in the adapter for those item that don't have have image, it is working fine. Thank you so much. And thanks everyone for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try **LinearLayout as parent with wrap_content height and width** and **give some specific values** for **child views in the parent layout** to make better layout, if there is **no image for particular data** then you can use **default images** for that **to make layout better and uniform.**